# How do I search in Mathematica SE with context ticks in the search bar?

Tags: support, search

Frequently I want to search for information on MMA.SE about symbols that are referred to by their full context. An example is `` System`Private`ArgumentsWithRules ``.

But, searching for `` System`Private`ArgumentsWithRules `` using the SE search bar yields no hits, despite [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164162/2048) clearly having that.  I had to find that page using Google search.

The resulting message  "We couldn't find anything for **systemprivateargumentswithrules**" shows that the context ticks get stripped away.

My question is: how do I search for symbols including the context ticks?

Comment: Replace the ticks with spaces `" "`?  [`System Private ArgumentsWithRules`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=System+Private+ArgumentsWithRules)

Comment: The deleted answer works, too (``System\`Private\`ArgumentsWithRules``) not sure why it was deleted...

Comment: @b3m2a1 Because I found though it works, it's wrong… the ` is actually ignored in this case. The issue becomes obvious when we try searching e.g. ``a`b``: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=a%5C%60b

Comment: @xzczd unfortunately based on this: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=mathematica I'm guessing there's no way to search for non alphanumerics